# Difference between login and user in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, administration

```
CREATE USER [anc] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[anc]
GO
```

what is the difference between the user and the login.

i am not clear as to y do we create these kind of users??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Logins are a server wide (instance level) objects. Their correct name is 'server principals' (see [`sys.server_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx)). Server wide privileges are granted to logins, like `create database` or `view server state` permissions.

Users are a database objects, correctly referred to as 'database principals' (see [`sys.database_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx)). They are the recipients of database permissions, like `create table` or `select`.

Ordinarily a login is mapped 1-to-1 to a user in each database, via a matching SID, but there are some exception, like all members of the `sysadmin` fixed server role are always mapped to `dbo`.

Users without login are a specific construct for Service Broker remote identities (see [Remote Service Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166042.aspx)) and for code signing. You should never have to create one in any other context, and if you do, you're likely doing it wrong. Users without login are never meant to be impersonated.

Answer (score 5):

A login is a login account for the entire SQL Server instance - an instance can contain numerous databases.

A user is defined at the database level, and is associated with a login to provide interactive access (privileges providing).

Comment: Old (like 2000), but applicable: http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_logins_and_users.html